# CSS flex box can't set second flex item width properly (angular7)

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

On an angular7 app I am trying to get the correct width for a bar chart.

The **.bar** width property has a **vw** unit. The issue is that it is based on the parent width (**.bar-container**) and I want it to be based on the flex-box item reserved width.

How can I fix that, without having the bar going out of the window ?

HTML piece:

```
<div class="bar-container" >
  <div class="element">some element</div>
  <div class="bar" [style.background-color]="randomColor" 
  [style.width]="maxValue" [style.border]="borderColor">
</div>
```

CSS piece:

```
.bar-container {
  width: 80vw;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
.bar {
  font-size: 1em;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #ffccc9;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvswjr) a simple app to reproduce the issue I have, on @Stackblitz

**EDIT**: 
For a better understanding, on the pic below, from first row to last we have width:100% , 70%, 50% ,20%. If it was based on the flex-box item reserved width we would have the good dimension but I don't know if it is possible?

[image]

Comment: Don't believe this is an option in CSS unless the `.element` is a fixed width. Flexbox can't calculate X% of an unknown.

Comment: `vw` is not based on any parent-width, it is based on the `viewport width`

Comment: yep my mistake I was thinking about % unit will edit